# getting error Interpreter busy while running tflite image segmentation modal in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tflite

> I/flutter (29838): PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
> I/flutter (29838):      at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:450)
> I/flutter (29838):      at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunSegmentationOnImage.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:1001)
> I/flutter (29838):      at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:161)
> I/flutter (29838):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
> I/flutter (29838):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
> I/flutter (29838):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
> I/flutter (29838):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
> I/flutter (29838):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> I/flutter (29838):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> I/flutter (29838):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> I/flutter (29838):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7417)
> I/flutter (29838):      at java.lang.reflec

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
title: 'Flutter Demo',
theme: ThemeData(
primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
),
home: const HomeScreen(),
);
}
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State\<HomeScreen\> createState() =\> \_HomeScreenState();
}

class \_HomeScreenState extends State\<HomeScreen\> {
var outputstring = 'noting';
var imagefile;
var isLoading = false;

var segmentedimage;
loadModal() {
Tflite.close();
Tflite.loadModel(
model: "assets/modals/model1.tflite",
labels: "assets/modals/labels1.txt",
).then((value) =\> print("success"));
Tflite.close();
}

@override
void initState() {
loadModal();
super.initState();
}

toggelloading() {
if (isLoading == true) {
setState(() {
isLoading = false;
});
} else {
setState(() {
isLoading = true;
});
}
}

Future\<File\> imagepick() async {
final picker = ImagePicker();
final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
print(pickedFile!.path);
return File(pickedFile.path);
}

Future\<String\> removebackround(File imagefile) async {
try {
toggelloading();

      await Tflite.runSegmentationOnImage(
        path: imagefile.path,
        imageMean: 127.5,
        imageStd: 127.5,
        asynch: false,
      ).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          segmentedimage = value;
          isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      toggelloading();
      return e.toString();
    }
    return "success";

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: const Text('Home'),
),
body: isLoading == false
? Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: \[
imagefile == null
? Container()
: Container(
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
child: Image.file(imagefile),
)),
segmentedimage != null
? Image.memory(segmentedimage)
: Container(),
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () async {
var pickimage = await imagepick();
setState(() {
imagefile = pickimage;
});
},
child: const Text('Pick Image')),
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () async {
var output = await removebackround(imagefile);
setState(() {
outputstring = output;
});
},
child: const Text('Removebackround')),
Text(
outputstring,
style: const TextStyle(
fontSize: 20,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
),
)
\],
),
),
)
: Container(
child: const Center(
child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
),
));
}
}
```